# What would be a successful ad campaign to change the general negative opinion of Djinni in popular culture?

Tags: fantasy-races

There's been any number of stories about genies, or djinni. Aladdin notwithstanding, the vast majority of those stories have painted the beings are at the very least mischievous, and at worst actively malicious against their "masters".

Some of those characterizations arise from the belief that djinni are demons, and inherently evil. A lot of those stories could be traced back to the "Monkey's paw" model, which are intended not to disparage djinni, but wishing.  In the stories, the wishes always go wrong, whether it be ascribed to malice or incompetence. The stories are really intended to give the message that "get rich quick" schemes and short-cuts are doomed to fail, and the only way to become a success is through your own hard work.

The end result of this propaganda is a general mistrust of the average Djinn. We've seen so many of these tales that the first question is always "what's the catch?" I expect when a Djinn is released from their confinement, ready to serve an assist, they're taken quite aback by the near-paranoia with which they're met.

I would think they'd want to do something about it.

So let's propose that a lamp is sent to the CEO of a major advertising and PR firm.  When the lamp is rubbed, a swarthy man (for lack of a better term) emerges, with green skin, pointy ears with numerous earrings, an impeccably tailored blazer, shirt and tie, matching harem pants, and patent leather curly-toe slippers.

"This may seem odd," he says, "but I have something to ask of *you*..."

What would be some solid tactics to make people "Genie-positive"?

The first slogan I can think of is "We only want to help".

Answer (score 2):

- Well, I'm sure you remember the TV show *I Dream of Jeannie*. Find some good-looking Djinni as spokespersons for Djinnihood. They're the ones who give TV interviews, even if your run-of-the-mill Djinni isn't nearly as sexy.
- Have any Djinni recite a short-but-clear disclaimer what they can and cannot do before they take wishes. Make the Djinni explain *in their own words* what they are about to do and what the limits are. (This could be problematic if not all Djinni join the campaign ...)
- Publicize the success of people who made feasible wishes. *I wish I had a 5-lb. bag of gold, legally handed to me in a tax accountant's office* instead of *I wish I had all the gold from Fort Knox.*

Comment: As bad as it sounds the whole disclaimer thing might be the better option. people are so wary of things these days they pay attention to disclaimers more often and it might actually lead to people trusting it more easily

Comment: Nick Pollotta had a great scene in one of the bureau 13 novels. Character finds a lamp, checks the aura, sees it's neutral. Rubs the lamp, and says "I need you to explain to be, in a language I can easily understand, exactly what I need to do to complete my mission".  The Genie looks at him and says "You've don'e this before, haven't you?"

Answer (score 1):

First you remove any resemblance to the fairytale character. Djinn are magical shapeshifting creatures. They can appear however they want.

One common practice is for Djinn to reshape their lamps into the door handle of their offices. Then when you touch the handle to open the door the Djinn appears inside the office as a modern man in a sharp suit with maybe an unusual number of earrings in one year. He looks like he was there all along. Most people in that office building are completely unaware there is a Djinn around.

Thus Djinn secretly work their way into all levels of society posing as regular humans. By the time their existence is made public probably one or more of your friends are Djinn without you knowing. At that point it's easier just to adapt to this new knowledge and keep the friends than suddenly starting to hate them.

The second thing is stop calling them Djinn or Genies. How are we supposed to take seriously anyone called after a fairytale character? Introduce a common term for these *people*. Make sure everyone starts using it. Then, as part of your PR campaign, sow some distrust and hate. Incite a riot and make sure the term appears on their sandwich boards. Put that on television. Now the only common term is a slur and everyone else can only refer to the Djinn as people.

Now they are everywhere and it is considered rude to distinguish them from people in general.

Over time the Djinni drop the ruse and start appearing in sultan-form -- assuming this is more comfortable to them.

Comment: "We prefer the term 'facilitator'..."